# Issue in Sending sms in background Phonegap

Tags: cordova

Could anyone help me in sending the SMS in background using Phonegap,

I have tried the sample in Git-hub but I have been getting the  error message

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'sms' of undefined at file:///android_asset/www/sendingsms.html:
```

Can anyone help me in this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a plugin using the native SMS Manager.

I just writed such plugin (working with Phonegap 2.5): https://github.com/Pyo25/phonegap-sms-sending-plugin

After having included the neeeded files, you just have to call the send method. Example:

```
var smsSendingPlugin = cordova.require('cordova/plugin/smssendingplugin');
smsSendingPlugin.send ("0032472345678", "Hello World !", function() {
    // message sent
}, function() {
    // message not sent
});
```